# getting text of custom listview item on its click

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a custom layout for the `ListView` which is as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/plain" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I click the item in a listview, I am getting error -

> 02-28 17:37:38.240: E/AndroidRuntime(20869): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-28 17:37:38.240: E/AndroidRuntime(20869):
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be
>   cast to android.widget.TextView

This is because now I am using custom listview layout as above which is wrapped in a linearlayout.

The error line is-

```
class ListItemClickedonPaired implements OnItemClickListener
    {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

            final String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString(); //ERROR HERE
         }
     }
```

**My question is-**

How to get the text of the clicked item (technically a textview) when we have these as a custom items of a listview defined with above xml ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

        TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        String info = tv.getText().toString();
     }
```

You inflate a `LinearLayout` for each row. What you are doing is casting `LinearLayout` to `TextView`.

You can also use `setTag` and `getTag`

You have used a id from the android framework. So it should be `android.R.id.text1` not `R.id.text1` coz you have  `android:id="@android:id/text1"`. It is a mistake which i have edited.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html

```
public static final int text1

Added in API level 1
Constant Value: 16908308 (0x01020014
```

Comment: Will it give the text of the *clicked* item ?

Comment: @VedPrakash did you try before posting the comment. I suggest you try it first.

Answer (score 1):

```
Instead of writing a text view inside a Linear layout make the TextView as the root Tag so that the view argument in the OnItemClick() returns the reference of text view, Now you can directly typecast the view object to the TextView.


    <TextView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

        switch(view.getId()) {

        case R.id.text1:
            final String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
           break;
        } 

     }
```

Comment: This won't work because it's an `OnItemClickListener`. It won't get fired for `TextViews`.